# Cannot perform an operation with converted label text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a bit stuck: I am trying to perform an if statement comparing a label.text that originally has a currency string created from `.ToString("C");`

and a decimal. I have tried converting the label to decimal since I'm going to be comparing it to a decimal but it keeps triggering an exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

here is my current code:

```
if(Convert.ToDecimal(SomeLabel.Text) > 1000.00m) { //DO SOMETHING } 
//SomeLabel.Text has a value of $1000.00
```

Comment: What is the value of `SomeLabel.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Better to have access to the original decimal value. Do you have it stored somewhere else you can compare with? Perhaps you can even `Tag` the label with the `decmial` at the same time you set it as the formatted string

Comment: @SonerGönül As shown in the code description, //SomeLabel.Text has a value of $1000.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //SomeLabel.Text has a value of $1000.00

The dollar sign is the reason for the issue. Yoa are probably using a different currency symbol. You can force it with `decimal.Parse`/`decimal.TryParse`(which handles invalid input):

```
string input = "$1000.00";
decimal decimalValue;
if(decimal.TryParse(input, out decimalValue))
{
    // using current CurrencySymbol, same as Convert.ToDecimal
    Console.WriteLine("Converted successfully: " + decimalValue);
}
else
{
    var usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    if (decimal.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Currency, usCulture, out decimalValue))
    {
        // using dollar sign as CurrencySymbol
        Console.WriteLine("Converted successfully with CultureInfo(en-US): " + decimalValue);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not be parsed to decimal");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Converted successfully with CultureInfo(en-US): 1000.00
```

It's worth noting that `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.CurrencySymbol` does not return the dollar sign(what i thought) but `¤`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Convert.ToDecimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9z3s65%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [`decimal.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly this method uses [`NumberStyles.Number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *by default*.

This is a composite style which includes `AllowDecimalPoint` but not `AllowCurrencySymbol` style *even* if your `CurrentCulture`'s [`CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `$` and [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `.`.

You can use [`decimal.parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` overlaod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes these as a parameters like;

```
string s = "$1000.00";
var d = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                      CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

`d` will be `1000` after parsing.

Comment: Nicely done, and it works well.  Too bad nobody else upvoted you for it and went with more complicated solutions!

Answer (score 0):

As per your example. your string value is **$1000.00**.

This contains a **$** sign that's why the compiler is unable to cast string to decimal.

try removing the unusable character by replace. Or try the method below

```
Regex digitsOnly = new Regex(@"[0-9.]");  // this regex matches only digits and decimal 
string decimalnumberstring = digitsOnly.Replace(SomeLabel.Text, "");// replace all non numbers (except decimal) with empty string
```

then try to convert the string value like below.

```
if(Convert.ToDecimal(decimalnumberstring) > 1000.00m) { //DO SOMETHING }
```

hope it helps....

Comment: _This contains a $ sign that's why the compiler is unable to cast string to decimal_ That's not true. And this is parsing, not casting.They are _really_ different.

Comment: The $ sign was appended from a .ToString("C"). Would Regex work with that?

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay [`C` is standard numeric format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString). That means you have _already_ a numeric value. Why do you generate it's string representation and parse it back? Why don't you use _that_ value instead?

Answer (score 0):

Take the Dollar Sign off of your text first:

Source: $1000

```
double result = 0M;
String value = SomeLabel.Text.Substring(1);
if (Double.TryParse(value, out result)) {
    //
}
return result;
```

Comment: There is _still_ no guaranteed to parse `1000.00` string with his `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: Perhaps. His post only shows *SomeLabel.Text has a value of $1000.00*. If all of his currency values are in this format, then stripping the first character off is the easiest way to go. In his profile, I see he is from the Philippines. There is no mention of his Current Culture settings.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
if(decimal.Parse(SomeLabel.Text) > 1000.00m)
{

}
```

Comment: This is the same as `Convert.ToDecimal(SomeLabel.Text)`.